# Post php,show page to user once

Tags: php, html

so in index.php:

```
 <form align="center" action="send.php" method="post">
 address:<input type="text" name="address"/><br>
  <input  id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="">
   </form>
```

i want when then user clicks on submit, redirect to send2.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  $_POST['address'];


}

header("location: send2.php"); 
exit;
```

and send2.php returns to index.php
when the user clicks on submit again i want to redirect him to this instead of send2.php.

```
header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/ptc/?failed=1');
```

only for 24 hours.after that when user click on submit i want him to redirect to send.php
please,i want kindly to write the code for me im still learning

Answer (score 0):

You can use database by saving the IP address of the user and it's visit time for the send2.php page. There's also cookies that you might want to consider.